# How to write imported functions that can be run ad-hoc but are also called by a master script?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say I have a master script that runs weekly via cronjob. This script imports a bunch of different functions from other Python files and runs their functions in sequence. I'd *also* like to be able to run a couple of the functions the master script runs but ad-hoc from the Terminal. What is the best way to construct both the master script and the individual files containing functions to be run? Example of current situation:

**master_script.py**

```
import do_bulk_things as b
import do_another_thing as a

b.do_first_bulk_thing()
b.do_second_bulk_thing()
if b.do_third_bulk_thing():
    a.my_other_thing()
```

**do_bulk_thinkgs.py**

```
def  do_first_bulk_thing():
    # Code

def do_second_bulk_thing():
    # Code

def do_third_bulk_thing():
    # Code
    if successful:
        return True
```

**do_another_thing.py**

```
def my_other_thing():
    # Code
```

If I want to run *my_other_thing()* without running the entire **master_script.py**, how and where should I be defining and calling everything? The imported files just have function definitions so I can't actually execute any function by running `python do_another_thing.py`; and I also shouldn't execute the function *my_other_thing()* within **do_another_thing.py** because then it will run on import. It seems to me that I need to restructure things, but I need some best practices.

Comment: Do you know how to use `sys.argv` and `argparse`? You could have `master_script.py` run your standard set of functions as a function, e.g. `standard()` by default (when no command line arguments are received) and then if you provide some command line arguments, have it run a different function `other_things()`. If that sounds useful and you don't know how to do it I will write up an answer. I'm assuming you do not want to do these ad-hoc activities from a python session. That would be easier and a different solution.

Comment: @kobejohn I know what `argv` does, but haven't used it or `argparse` before. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) on `argparse` is more than enough to show me the way. If using cmd line arguments is a better practice or better way than `__main__` for a particular reason then I'd like to hear why. It seems like using args would require a more modification of the existing code but would in the end provide more flexibility down the road.

Comment: If you can use a python session to do your ad-hoc work, then yes, `__main__` detection was the other solution I was talking about and it's easier than worrying about parsing command line arguments. Because you are working with cron-jobs I thought maybe constraints prevent you from working in a python session. I'll comment on your answer if I have any improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to attempt to answer my own question after [some more research](http://youtu.be/tKTZoB2Vjuk?t=11m52s), which then [lead me here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do). Execute the defined and imported functions within **do_bulk_thinks.py** and **do_another_thing.py**, but use `__main__` to stop the functions from running when they're imported. So **master_script.py** remains unchanged, but the other files would have:

**do_bulk_things.py**

```
def  do_first_bulk_thing():
    # Code

def do_second_bulk_thing():
    # Code

def do_third_bulk_thing():
    # Code
    if successful:
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_first_bulk_thing()
    do_second_bulk_thing()
    do_third_bulk_thing()
```

And **do_another_thing.py**

```
def my_other_thing():
    # Code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_other_thing()
```

Comment: You've got the main idea. Actually in this particular example, the `__main__` detection is not necessary because you are only defining functions. Nothing will change for you. However if you have some other code inside of `bulk` or `another`, then that could be wrapped up in a `main()` to avoid being run when you just want to import the functions.